# Android Custom widget

Tags: android

I want to create a android widget like the Notification box in android.
Image is pasted below. How to achieve this.[image: facebook App notification box]

Comment: I have been trying to create a cutom alertbox with listview inside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this example for Creating custom tooltip popup window

[image]
[How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

and also try  [NewQuickAction3D](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69670844/lorensiuswlt-NewQuickAction3D-v1.0.1-0-g4273b56.zip)  example

Comment: yes thats very close to what I need..i will further work on it..thanks